# export icon from illustrator to Photoshop with transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transparency

I have an icon in illustrator but when I export to Photoshop I get white around the shadow in the image. Please advise how to remove the white. I have the icon in layers.

[image: example]

original ai file
http://www23.zippyshare.com/v/43531370/file.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the shadow created? Black to white gradient filled ellipse?

Change it to a black to black gradient and from 0% to 100% opacity. (CS5 or newer)

[image: Gradient]

I often find it's better to copy and past the AI artwork into Photoshop without shadows, then rebuild the shadows in Photoshop.

### Edit

Yes it's as I suspected, you've got a black to white gradient there. So naturally, the white will transfer to Photoshop as well.

Select the White Gradient Stop and set its opacity to 0%.

[image]

Comment: dont know it is another person work. I included the ai file please try it......thanks

Comment: Many Thanks my friend. I also made the gradient black to black to make the shadow heavier as you suggested.